# Changing a small region of my texture causes the rest of the texture to go black

Tags: macos, textures, metal

I have an application that does some calculations on the CPU on multiple threads. Each thread calculates a 64x64 pixel region of an output image. When a thread has completed its calculations, it uploads the calculated pixel data to a `MTLTexture` via `-[MTLTexture replaceRegion:]`. Before any of the CPU threads start, I have placed a low-res version of the full result into the texture, and I'd like for the threads on the CPU to overwrite the image data as they calculate it at a higher resolution.

I have this working for the most part, but when the first call to `-replaceRegion:` happens, it appears to clear the texture to black, and then replaces the 64x64 region as requested.

Here's how I'm creating the texture:

```
MTLTextureDescriptor*   outputTextureDesc   = [MTLTextureDescriptor texture2DDescriptorWithPixelFormat:MTLPixelFormatBGRA8Unorm
                                                                                             width:viewportSize.width
                                                                                            height:viewportSize.height
                                                                                         mipmapped:NO];
outputTextureDesc.usage = MTLTextureUsageShaderWrite | MTLTextureUsageShaderRead | MTLTextureUsageRenderTarget;
_outputTexture = [device newTextureWithDescriptor:outputTextureDesc];
```

Then, when I want to put the low-res version of the output into the texture, I copy it from another texture like this:

```
const Vertex2D quadVertices[] =
{
    //Pixel Positions, Texture Coordinates
    { { viewportSize.x / 2.0,  viewportSize.y / -2.0 }, { right, bottom } },
    { { viewportSize.x / -2.0, viewportSize.y / -2.0 }, { left, bottom } },
    { { viewportSize.x / -2.0, viewportSize.y / 2.0 }, { left, top } },

    { { viewportSize.x / 2.0,  viewportSize.y / -2.0 }, { right, bottom } },
    { { viewportSize.x / -2.0, viewportSize.y / 2.0 }, { left, top } },
    { { viewportSize.x / 2.0, viewportSize.y / 2.0 }, { right, top } },
};

MTLRenderPassDescriptor *renderPassDescriptor = [MTLRenderPassDescriptor renderPassDescriptor];
renderPassDescriptor.colorAttachments [ 0 ].texture = _outputTexture;
renderPassDescriptor.colorAttachments [ 0 ].loadAction = MTLLoadActionDontCare;
renderPassDescriptor.colorAttachments [ 0 ].storeAction = MTLStoreActionStore;

if(renderPassDescriptor != nil)
{
    id<MTLCommandBuffer> commandBuffer = [commandQueue commandBuffer];
    commandBuffer.label = @"Copy Selection Command Buffer";

    // Create a render command encoder so we can render into something
    id<MTLRenderCommandEncoder> renderEncoder =
        [commandBuffer renderCommandEncoderWithDescriptor:renderPassDescriptor];
    renderEncoder.label = @"Copy Selection Command Encoder";

    [renderEncoder setViewport:(MTLViewport){0.0, 0.0, viewportSize.x, viewportSize.y, -1.0, 1.0 }];

    [renderEncoder setRenderPipelineState:renderPipelineState];

    [renderEncoder setVertexBytes:quadVertices
                           length:sizeof(quadVertices)
                          atIndex:MBV_VertexIndex];

    [renderEncoder setVertexBytes:&viewportSize
                           length:sizeof(viewportSize)
                          atIndex:MBV_ViewportSize];

    [renderEncoder setFragmentTexture:oldRender
                              atIndex:MBF_Texture];

    // Draw the vertices of our triangles
    [renderEncoder drawPrimitives:MTLPrimitiveTypeTriangle
                      vertexStart:0
                      vertexCount:6];

    [renderEncoder endEncoding];
    [commandBuffer commit];
    [commandBuffer waitUntilCompleted];
}
```

I also tried changing the `renderPassDescriptor.colorAttachment [ 0 ].loadAction` to `MTLLoadActionLoad` instead of `MTLLoadActionDontCare`, as the docs says:

> The existing contents of the texture are preserved.

but it didn't make any difference.

Finally, when a thread finishes, it uploads its 64x64 pixel result by doing this:

```
MTLRegion currentRegion = { { colStart, rowStart, 0}, { colEnd - colStart, rowEnd - rowStart, 1 } };
[_outputTexture replaceRegion:currentRegion
                  mipmapLevel:0
                    withBytes:_outputBitmap + (rowStart * (int)viewportSize.width) + colStart
                  bytesPerRow:viewportSize.width * sizeof(*_outputBitmap)];
```

If I use the Metal debugging tools to look at the texture after the initial copy of the low-res data, it contains the correct pixels. But after the first call to `-replaceRegion:`, everything other than the region replaced is black. Subsequent calls to `-replaceRegion:` work correctly and do not overwrite the previously written results.

I should mention that this texture is also being displayed as it's updated  by an `MTKView`. I do sometimes see the low-res copy for a frame or two before the high-res tiles start filling in. Any idea why the call to `-replaceRegion:` would clear the texture? (Or what else might be clearing the texture if it's not the call to `-replaceRegion:`?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming this is on macOS and not iOS, the texture's storage mode defaults to `MTLStorageModeManaged`. That means that you must explicitly synchronize the texture to get the CPU to "see" any modifications made by the GPU. Since your initial low-resolution image is drawn into the texture, that's only on the GPU unless/until you synchronize. Since you're failing to do that, the CPU has uninitialized data. When you use the CPU to replace a region, it's modifying its (uninitialized) copy and then pushing that to the GPU. That replaces the drawn content.

To synchronize, you should create a blit command encoder (`MTLBlitCommandEncoder`) and use that to encode a synchronization command using `-synchronizeResource:` or (if you want to be more selective) `-synchronizeTexture:slice:level:`.

Finally, I'm not sure, but I'd be concerned about the thread safety of the various `-replaceRegion:...` calls. So, you should use a serial dispatch queue or something to serialize those.

Comment: This is on macOS, so I will give that a try. Thank you for the suggestion. I am planning on adding some serialization, too, just haven't gotten to it yet.